# Does IPFS use HTTP?

Tags: ipfs

How do nodes communicate in the IPFS network? Aren't they still using HTTP?

If not, how is JS-IPFS able to interact directly with the IPFS network without the need for a HTTP gateway server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPFS uses peer-to-peer communication using the `libp2p` library which uses multiaddress(`multiaddr`). `multiaddr` is a way of communication using multiple protocols. The [JS version](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/) of the libp2p library allows you to configure Transports which are used to communicate between peers. Here's a list of supported transports as shown on the [configuration guide](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/blob/master/doc/CONFIGURATION.md#transport).

- libp2p/js-libp2p-tcp
- libp2p/js-libp2p-webrtc-star
- libp2p/js-libp2p-webrtc-direct
- libp2p/js-libp2p-websockets
- libp2p/js-libp2p-utp (WIP)

The `js-libp2p-tcp` and `js-libp2p-utp` cannot be used in a browser.

IPFS & libp2p: https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/libp2p/